# How can I display images in Django media directory in the HTML template?

Tags: python, django

When I call an image in a template as shown below, it works:

```
    <img src=http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/img/profile/8.jpg class="avatar rounded-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar">
```

I tried to do the same using URL:

```
    src = {{MEDIA_URL}}/img/profile/8.jpg
    src = "{{MEDIA_URL}}/img/profile/8.jpg"
    src = "media/img/profile/8.jpg"
```

it did not work despite the variations shown above.

My `settings.py`:

```py
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/media/')
```

My `models.py`:

```py
class UserFiles(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def profile_image_upload_path(instance, filename):
        return f'img/profile/{filename}'

    picture = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=profile_image_upload_path, blank=True)

    def profile_letter_upload_path(instance, filename):
        return f'files/letter/{filename}'

    letter = models.FileField(upload_to=profile_letter_upload_path, blank=True)

    def profile_medical_upload_path(instance, filename):
        return f'files/medical/{filename}'

    medical = models.FileField(
        upload_to=profile_medical_upload_path, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

My `views.py`:

```py
def view_profile(request):

    user_files = UserFiles.objects.all()
    user_fields = Profile.objects.all()

    context = {
        'title': 'profile',
        'files': user_files,
        'user_fields': user_fields,
    }

    return render(request, 'member/profile.html', context)
```

My `urls.py`:

```py
    urlpatterns = [
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Can someone show me how to show files in my front-end using this tag, or similar syntax media so I can view typing image file as a url in the browser?

```
    {% for fields in user_fields %}

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> 
       {{fields.label}}</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id=" 
       {{fields.name}}"
                                value="{{fields.value}}">
                        </div>

                    </div>
     {% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks in advance, yeah I tried that way too using a for loop and ```{{image.url}}``` but did not work.

Comment: Iteration variable is `fields`. `UserFiles` model field is `picture`. it's `fields.picture.url`, not `image.url`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you start by changing your `settings.py` media settings to:

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') # notice there's no `/`
```

As for displaying the images in an HTML template, I recommend @Ivan Starostin's suggestion,

```
 {% for fields in user_fields %}

   <img src="{{ fields.picture.url }}" class="avatar rounded-circle img-thumbnail" alt="avatar">

     {% endfor %}
```

The last question involving is a bit unclear.

Comment: Thanks for the sugession I'll try it.

Comment: sorry it was my mistake your sugession was helpful to corrcet the error.